# How to create a button and segue from titleView image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar, segue

Having a problem with customizing the navigationBar. I have changed the titleView text to an image through coding. Now I want the image to be a clickable button with a segue to the starting page (for example a home button to the main viewController). How do I make the titleView image into a button (or item) and how do I create a segue from it. I suppose it has to be done in code since I haven't found any other means of doing it. If you have a solution, please be thorough - I'm a beginner.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please add your code so we can see what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a custom `UIView` containing `UIButton` and `UIImageView` to the `titleView` of `navigationItem`.

**Example:**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 80, height: 30))
    button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showMainVC), for: .touchUpInside)

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 80, height: 30))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image")

    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 80, height: 30))
    customView.addSubview(imageView)
    customView.addSubview(button)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = customView
}

func showMainVC()
{
    //TODO:
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Tanks for your help! :)